# Javascript 4-image slideshow w/ arrays & setTimeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, string-concatenation

```
<script type=text/javascript>

var topLeftImages = ["op.jpg", "qa.jpg", "fl.jpg", "eatgr.jpg", "na.jpg", "ctcc.jpg", "na.jpg", "oacahu.jpg", "hc.jpg", "sup.jpg", "oa.jpg", "rffcc.jpg"];
var topRightImages = ["eatgr.jpg", "ulandscaping.jpg", "fp.jpg", "clf.jpg", "lss.jpg", "sup.jpg", "ulandlord.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "lss.jpg", "lp.jpg", "ulandlord.jpg", "qa.jpg"];
var bottomLeftImages = ["poss.jpg", "un.jpg", "pocsik.jpg", "sep.jpg", "rms.jpg", "fp.jpg", "al.jpg", "un.jpg", "sep.jpg", "op.jpg", "al.jpg", "oacahu.jpg"];
var bottomRightImages = ["nup.jpg", "clf.jpg", "rffcc.jpg", "sla.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "pocsik.jpg", "fp.jpg", "np.jpg", "lwtgr.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "lcsik.jpg", "poss.jpg"];

for(var i = 0, l = topLeftImages.length; i < l; i++)
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('myimage1').src = "images\\" + "op.jpg";
        document.getElementById('myimage2').src = "images\\" + topRightImages[i];
        document.getElementById('myimage3').src = "images\\" + bottomLeftImages[i];
        document.getElementById('myimage4').src = "images\\" + bottomRightImages[i];
    }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

Associated HTML:

```
<img id="myimage1" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/apple_sky_blue_aurora-wide.jpg" width="400" />
<img id="myimage2" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/apple_sky_blue_aurora-wide.jpg" width="400" />
<img id="myimage3" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/apple_sky_blue_aurora-wide.jpg" width="400" />
<img id="myimage4" src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/apple_sky_blue_aurora-wide.jpg" width="400" />
```

This code is meant to show four images, and every 10 seconds, switch all four images simultaneously, going through all of my images in my four arrays. The images are in the images/ directory above my HTML file that contains this code. For testing purposes, I changed `myimage1` to change to op.jpg only. This works and correctly shows op.jpg. However, when querying the arrays, instead of the file names, I get `undefined`. **That is problem number one.**

**Problem number two**, when I change my for loop to a more normal looking one like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < l2; i++)
```

The script stops working entirely (doesn't show op.jpg and doesn't even try to change the images)... what the hell!

I'm using Firefox and Google Chrome for testing purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Could someone explain this to me please? I'm still not quite understanding what to do from the possible duplicate. I'm still learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like that instead:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var topLeftImages = ["op.jpg", "qa.jpg", "fl.jpg", "eatgr.jpg", "na.jpg", "ctcc.jpg", "na.jpg", "oacahu.jpg", "hc.jpg", "sup.jpg", "oa.jpg", "rffcc.jpg"];
        var topRightImages = ["eatgr.jpg", "ulandscaping.jpg", "fp.jpg", "clf.jpg", "lss.jpg", "sup.jpg", "ulandlord.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "lss.jpg", "lp.jpg", "ulandlord.jpg", "qa.jpg"];
        var bottomLeftImages = ["poss.jpg", "un.jpg", "pocsik.jpg", "sep.jpg", "rms.jpg", "fp.jpg", "al.jpg", "un.jpg", "sep.jpg", "op.jpg", "al.jpg", "oacahu.jpg"];
        var bottomRightImages = ["nup.jpg", "clf.jpg", "rffcc.jpg", "sla.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "pocsik.jpg", "fp.jpg", "np.jpg", "lwtgr.jpg", "lqbc.jpg", "lcsik.jpg", "poss.jpg"];

        var i = 0;
        var max = 12;

        setInterval(function()
        {
            var index = i % max;
            document.getElementById('myimage1').src = "images\\" + topLeftImages[index];
            document.getElementById('myimage2').src = "images\\" + topRightImages[index];
            document.getElementById('myimage3').src = "images\\" + bottomLeftImages[index];
            document.getElementById('myimage4').src = "images\\" + bottomRightImages[index];
            i++;
        }, 10000);
    });   
</script>
```

jsFiddle with some example images http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/8/

Comment: This doesn't do anything at all in Firefox or Chrome. Can you provide a JSFiddle of this in action by chance?

Comment: works in both FF and Chrome for me, maybe you have missed something

Comment: You have already said in your post that your script stopped to work completely. JsFiddle works for you?

Comment: Have you tried Firebug in Firefox to debug if there are some errors on console?

Comment: JSFiddle works... but when I post it into a test HTML file on my comp it doesn't work anymore. Any idea why that would be? It doesn't do anything in either FF or Chrome.

Comment: Your JSFiddle has **$(document).ready(function ()...**, your answer doesn't. Do I need that piece?

Comment: Ah yes that's true add it there and check again, I'll update answer

Comment: be aware that $(document).ready uses jQuery, if you don't include that just move it to some function and call when is needed